# How do we write unit test cases for self calling functions using mocha in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocha.js

```
(
async ()=>{

// code

})();
```

This code is present in one js file and which is not exported as well. I want to import and write unit test cases for above self calling function but unable to find any soln.

I tried using rewire module but not able to invoke self calling function.

Please suggest.

Comment: Sometimes you need to change the code in order to make it (more) testable. This is one of those times.

Comment: U mean no other way we can write test cases. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can write unit test by mocking dependencies.
eg. consider below code snippet.

**src/script.js**

```
const fun = require('./function.js');
(async ()=>{
    const resp = await Promise.all([
        fun.getData('type1'),
        fun.getData('type2')]);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));
})();
```

then test case will be like this (**test/script.test.js**):

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const fun = require('../src/function');

const expect = chai.expect;
describe('function.js', function(){

    beforeEach(async () => {
        sandbox = sinon.createSandbox();   
    });

    it('should load data', function(done){
        const mockType1 ={'url1':'http://localhost:3000'};
        const mockType2 ={'client_id':'123','mongourl':'http://localhost:27001'};
        
        const vaultStub = sandbox.stub(fun, 'getData')
            .resolves(mockType1 )
            .resolves(mockType2);
        require('../src/script.js');
        expect(vaultStub.calledTwice).to.be.true;
        done();
    });

});
```

Hope this will help you. Thanks.